# Two DataGridViews; lining up columns

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

The project on which I'm currently working has two `datagridviews` that are meant to compare two versions of similar data (same number and name of columns). I'd like to resize all the columns so that they fit two criteria:

1) Autosize to fit data (that's easy)

2) So the columns are lined up such that for any column COL,  `gridA[COL].Width = Max(gridA[COL].Width`, `gridB[COL].Width`), and the same for `gridB[COL].Width`

The problem I'm encountering is, when you do an auto-resize, the `Width` property doesn't show you the ACTUAL width (it displays the width before the auto-resize, I guess).

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to resize columns that allows for more control. I can't believe I missed it the first time around.

One can use the `DataGridViewColumn.GetPreferredWidth(...)` method to get the autosize width.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that one as well.

Answer (score 0):

For auto-resize there's the FillWeight property.

If you set both gridviews' AutoSizeColumnsMode to Fill, you can read the FillWeight off the first and apply it to the second. You'll probably have to do it for all the columns though.

Comment: Yes. Let me clarify - I can auto-size it fine; that part was added for completeness. But if the AutoSizeMode that is affecting the column is not "None", the Width displayed is not the "actual" width.

I need to be able to do something like set the widths of the cols on the second grid to those of the first one (which are autosized)